# Reentrancy check on external call

Tags: solidity, contract-development, reentrant-attacks

If I have two external functions in two contracts (A and B), where A calls B, B's called function has an `onlyA()` modifier, and B's called function sends ETH to an external address, is it logical to check for reentrancy in A and B? Or is it safe enough to check for reentrancy on A only?

Comment: What exactly does the `onlyA()` modifier do? Only the address of contract A can call that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very broad question and I'm not sure what the `onlyA()` modifier does. Let's say it checks to make sure that Contract B's method (which is `external`) and can only be called if `msg.sender` is the address of Contract A. In this case, then yes, you will only need to make sure Contract A checks for reentrancy, because the function is acting as if it were an internal method of A. But if that's the case, then why isn't it part of Contract A?

Comment: You gave me the answer already. Your open questions are open since I left out some context in order to make the question as simple as possible but still direct to the point.